# Apache Spark with Delta Lake on Local Machine

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I'm trying to learn more about Spark and the Delta Lake format. To try to save on Databricks costs, while learning and experimenting, I've been trying to set Spark with Delta up on my local dev laptop.

No issues getting Spark working by itself, that seems to be fine; I can read csv's into a dataframe, do some transorms and generally the Spark side seems fine. The issue when I try to introduce support for Delta Lake.

```py
import pyspark
from delta import *

builder = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("trying_delta") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.2.2")
    

spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()

df = (spark
        .read
        .format('csv')
        .option('header', 'true')
        .option('inferSchema', 'true')
        .load('dataset.csv'))

df.show()

spark.stop()
```

In that code I'm not even trying to write the dataframe out as delta, I'm just trying to get the Spark session working with the support for Delta, read some data then exit the session.

What I get is:

```
PS F:\PySpark> python main.py
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/C:/spark/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/jars/ivy-2.5.1.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
Ivy Default Cache set to: C:\Users\admin\.ivy2\cache
The jars for the packages stored in: C:\Users\admin\.ivy2\jars
io.delta#delta-core_2.12 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-36e786d4-a8a3-4e4a-8a04-79deea9379ca;1.0
        confs: [default]
        found io.delta#delta-core_2.12;2.2.0 in central
        found io.delta#delta-storage;2.2.0 in central
        found org.antlr#antlr4-runtime;4.8 in central
:: resolution report :: resolve 172ms :: artifacts dl 13ms
        :: modules in use:
        io.delta#delta-core_2.12;2.2.0 from central in [default]
        io.delta#delta-storage;2.2.0 from central in [default]  
        org.antlr#antlr4-runtime;4.8 from central in [default]  
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
        |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |      default     |   3   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   3   |   0   |
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-36e786d4-a8a3-4e4a-8a04-79deea9379ca
        confs: [default]
        0 artifacts copied, 3 already retrieved (0kB/9ms)
23/03/13 13:05:39 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
23/03/13 13:05:55 WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped
23/03/13 13:05:55 ERROR Inbox: Ignoring error
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManagerMasterEndpoint$$register(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:582)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint$$anonfun$receiveAndReply$1.applyOrElse(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.$anonfun$process$1(Inbox.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$MessageLoop$$receiveLoop(MessageLoop.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop$$anon$1.run(MessageLoop.scala:41)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

At which point I'm a bit lost as to why there would be a null Pointer in the BlockManagerMasterEndpoint, not that I even know what the BlockManagerMasterEndpoint even is!

I'm using a Windows 10 laptop, loads of CPU and Mem. I'm using Spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3 download of Spark. Java is:

```
java version "1.8.0_361"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_361-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.361-b09, mixed mode)
```

When I use a different sample code without the builder block for Delta Eg:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName('zod')
    .getOrCreate()
)

df = (spark
        .read
        .format('csv')
        .option('header', 'true')
        .option('inferSchema', 'true')
        .load('dataset.csv'))

df.show()
```

That works absolutely fine, so I think I have a fundamentally ok install of Spark itself?

Would be very grateful for any suggestions. Many thanks!

UPDATE:

Now trying using using the sample code:

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("trying_delta")\
  .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.2.0")\
  .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")\
  .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")\
  .getOrCreate()

df = (spark
        .read
        .format('csv')
        .option('header', 'true')
        .option('inferSchema', 'true')
        .load('dataset.csv'))

df.show()

df.write.format('delta').saveAsTable('test_table')

spark.stop()
```

And also using spark-submit as suggested. Still getting same error. Any advice, suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you see if you can run this using pyspark shell, e.g., 

```
pyspark --packages io.delta:${DELTA_PACKAGE_VERSION} \
--conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" \
--conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"
```

and see if this fails or works as this may point to if its the builder option.

Comment: Hi 

I get:

```F:\PySpark> pyspark --packages io.delta:${DELTA_PACKAGE_VERSION} \ --conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" \ --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"
Error: pyspark does not support any application options.

Usage: bin\pyspark.cmd [options]```

Comment: Can you open a Pyspark session with the same jars/dependencies and try using the builder method from delta package ? This builder is not doing anything significant other than adding the delta related jars to your driver class path. Can you do a fresh installation of the delta package as outlined in https://delta.io/learn/getting-started/ . You may also specify the details of your local machine to troubleshoot further.

Comment: Which version of `delta-spark` are you using? I copied your example and it works for me with `pyspark==3.3.0`, `delta-spark==2.3.0`. But also I am using MacOS and not Windows, which could make a difference

Answer (score 0):

1. I changed a little bit of you code as below, it will save the csv file as a delta table named test_table:

```
# cat spark-delta.py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("trying_delta")\
  .config("spark.jars.packages", ",io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.2.0")\
  .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")\
  .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")\
  .getOrCreate()

df = (spark
        .read
        .format('csv')
        .option('header', 'true')
        .option('inferSchema', 'true')
        .load('dataset.csv'))

df.show()

df.write.format('delta').saveAsTable('test_table')

spark.stop()

# cat dataset.csv
name,age
Tom,10
Tim,12
```

2. Run the code through spark-submit instead of python

```
# spark-submit --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.2.0 spark-delta.py
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/home/setup/apache/spark/spark-3.3.2/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/jars/ivy-2.5.1.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
Ivy Default Cache set to: /root/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /root/.ivy2/jars
io.delta#delta-core_2.12 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-e2116753-3352-4b1e-82ff-d2ec3c2729a0;1.0
        confs: [default]
        found io.delta#delta-core_2.12;2.2.0 in central
        found io.delta#delta-storage;2.2.0 in central
        found org.antlr#antlr4-runtime;4.8 in central
:: resolution report :: resolve 146ms :: artifacts dl 6ms
        :: modules in use:
        io.delta#delta-core_2.12;2.2.0 from central in [default]
        io.delta#delta-storage;2.2.0 from central in [default]
        org.antlr#antlr4-runtime;4.8 from central in [default]
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
        |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |      default     |   3   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   3   |   0   |
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-e2116753-3352-4b1e-82ff-d2ec3c2729a0
        confs: [default]
        0 artifacts copied, 3 already retrieved (0kB/5ms)
23/03/15 11:21:06 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
23/03/15 11:21:06 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.3.2
.
.
.
23/03/15 11:21:11 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 13.471381 ms
+----+---+
|name|age|
+----+---+
| Tom| 10|
| Tim| 12|
+----+---+
.
.
.
Writing page checksums is: on
23/03/15 11:21:12 INFO ParquetWriteSupport: Initialized Parquet WriteSupport with Catalyst schema:
{
  "type" : "struct",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "name",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  }, {
    "name" : "age",
    "type" : "integer",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  } ]
}
and corresponding Parquet message type:
message spark_schema {
  optional binary name (STRING);
  optional int32 age;
}
.
.
.
3/03/15 11:21:17 INFO Snapshot: [tableId=ebbd998a-e77c-4444-a880-da8a4d6e00be] DELTA: Done
23/03/15 11:21:17 INFO Snapshot: [tableId=ebbd998a-e77c-4444-a880-da8a4d6e00be] Created snapshot Snapshot(path=file:/home/setup/apache/spark/spark-3.3.2/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/spark-warehouse/test_table/_delta_log, version=0, metadata=Metadata(e929fd83-9bee-457d-8a43-c3464f871118,null,null,Format(parquet,Map()),{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"name","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"age","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]},List(),Map(),Some(1678850472039)), logSegment=LogSegment(file:/home/setup/apache/spark/spark-3.3.2/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/spark-warehouse/test_table/_delta_log,0,WrappedArray(DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus{path=file:/home/setup/apache/spark/spark-3.3.2/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/spark-warehouse/test_table/_delta_log/00000000000000000000.json; isDirectory=false; length=1163; replication=1; blocksize=33554432; modification_time=1678850473139; access_time=1678850473135; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false; hasAcl=false; isEncrypted=false; isErasureCoded=false}),List(),None,1678850473139), checksumOpt=None)
23/03/15 11:21:17 INFO DeltaLog: Updated snapshot to Snapshot(path=file:/home/setup/apache/spark/spark-3.3.2/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/spark-warehouse/test_table/_delta_log, version=0, metadata=Metadata(e929fd83-9bee-457d-8a43-c3464f871118,null,null,Format(parquet,Map()),{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"name","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"age","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]},List(),Map(),Some(1678850472039)), logSegment=LogSegment(file:/home/setup/apache/spark/spark-3.3.2/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/spark-warehouse/test_table/_delta_log,0,WrappedArray(DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus{path=file:/home/setup/apache/spark/spark-3.3.2/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/spark-warehouse/test_table/_delta_log/00000000000000000000.json; isDirectory=false; length=1163; replication=1; blocksize=33554432; modification_time=1678850473139; access_time=1678850473135; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false; hasAcl=false; isEncrypted=false; isErasureCoded=false}),List(),None,1678850473139), checksumOpt=None)
23/03/15 11:21:17 INFO OptimisticTransaction: [tableId=ebbd998a,txnId=737673f0] Committed delta #0 to file:/home/setup/apache/spark/spark-3.3.2/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/spark-warehouse/test_table/_delta_log
```

3. The code of read data from delta table

```
# cat read-delta.py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("trying_delta")\
  .config("spark.jars.packages", ",io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.2.0")\
  .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")\
  .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")\
  .getOrCreate()

delta_df = spark.read.format('delta').load('file:///home/setup/apache/spark/spark-3.3.2/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/spark-warehouse/test_table')
delta_df.show()

spark.stop()
```

4. Run read-delta.py

```
# spark-submit --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.2.0 read-delta.py 
vysettings.xml
Ivy Default Cache set to: /root/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /root/.ivy2/jars
io.delta#delta-core_2.12 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-b0cdd8a5-e9a5-4b48-9299-11cf1208e22e;1.0
        confs: [default]
        found io.delta#delta-core_2.12;2.2.0 in central
        found io.delta#delta-storage;2.2.0 in central
        found org.antlr#antlr4-runtime;4.8 in central
:: resolution report :: resolve 143ms :: artifacts dl 5ms
        :: modules in use:
        io.delta#delta-core_2.12;2.2.0 from central in [default]
        io.delta#delta-storage;2.2.0 from central in [default]
        org.antlr#antlr4-runtime;4.8 from central in [default]
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
        |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |      default     |   3   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   3   |   0   |
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
.
.
.
23/03/15 11:33:19 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 4 finished: showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0, took 0.390439 s
23/03/15 11:33:19 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 4.761534 ms
+----+---+
|name|age|
+----+---+
| Tom| 10|
| Tim| 12|
+----+---+

23/03/15 11:33:19 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://server01:4041
23/03/15 11:33:19 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
23/03/15 11:33:19 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
23/03/15 11:33:19 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
23/03/15 11:33:19 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
23/03/15 11:33:19 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
23/03/15 11:33:19 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
23/03/15 11:33:20 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
23/03/15 11:33:20 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-7f4161bc-ae86-4c79-9d4f-2e8fcb2433a4
23/03/15 11:33:20 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-5133a402-3d98-4f3f-82e6-6a8c59e1e113
```

Comment: Hi Xu
Amazing reply!! Thank you. I get:

PS F:\PySpark> spark-submit --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.2.0 test.py

<stuff>

23/03/15 19:45:27 ERROR Inbox: Ignoring error
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManagerMasterEndpoint$$register(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:582)  
        at rg.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint$$anonfun$receiveAndReply$1.applyOrElse(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.$anonfun$process$1(Inbox.scala:103)

Comment: Could you please try the spark-delta.py I post before? Or you can paste the test.py here, I can try it.

Comment: Thanks.  I have updated the question with the code I'm trying now (exactly as you specified), but still getting same error. I'm using the exact spark-delta.py code and now using spark-submit to run it, but still the same.

Comment: Looks like a typo in this `.config`: drop the comma here: `",io.delta`